# Generating Point Sets for Reciprocal Function

Tags: python

everyone.

I am writing a function that generates the points to graph a reciprocal function. Here is the code :

```
def genRecp(xValrange=3, shiftHoriz=0, shiftVert=0, vertStrech=1, horizStrech=1):
    #setup variables for processing
    xrangeP = xValrange
    xrangeN = xrangeP - xrangeP * 2
    vals = []
    #start adding values to array
    while xrangeN <= xrangeP:
        curX = xrangeN
        if curX == 0:
            xrangeN += 1
            continue
        #generate y values
        curY = vertStrech * (1 / (horizStrech * curX - shiftHoriz)) + shiftVert
        newVal = [curX, curY]
        #add value to array
        vals.append(newVal)
        #LOOOOOOP!
        xrangeN +=1
    return vals
```

The code seems fine, however, when I execute the following command :

```
genRecp()
```

I receive this output : `[[-3, -1], [-2, -1], [-1, -1], [1, 1], [2, 0], [3, 0]]` which is clearly not an array of base points for a reciprocal function.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your default parameter values are all integers, and the line that calculates `curY` uses integer division `/`. That rounds your calculated values to an integer.

Do something to make your values non-integers, namely floating-point, force your values to float by wrapping the numerator and denominator in the `float()` typecast function. Or perhaps change the `1` constant in that line to `1.0`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. After changing all values to float, it all worked out.

Comment: If you mean you changed only the default values, I recommend that you go beyond that. The caller may use all integer parameters, and that may result in integer coordinates.